# while run cron with lumen : There are no commands defined in the "insert" namespace.

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have written code for cron command as below in lumen (micro framwork of laravel)

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Models\EmailDump;
use DB;

/**
 * dumpEmails Class
 *
 * This cron is to dump emails with cron use
 *
 * @author Hetal Gohel <hetal.gohel@brainvire.com>
 *
 */

class dumpEmails extends Command {

    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'insert:emails';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'This cron is to dump emails with cron use';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    { 
       echo "1";die;       
    }
}
```

in kernel file defined as below,

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \Laravelista\LumenVendorPublish\VendorPublishCommand::class,
        '\App\Console\Commands\dumpEmails',
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
//    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
//    {
//        return $schedule;
//    }
}
```

I have fired command from console as below,

```
php artisan insert:emails
```

while run this command getting error as below,

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  There are no commands defined in the "insert" namespace.

please help me to resolve this issue.thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `__construct` and keep just the `handle` method.

Also, when you are listing under `$commands at Kernel` you need to specify the class.

So your

```
`\App\Console\Commands\dumpEmails`
```

becomes

```
    DumpEmails::class
```

A few extra tips:

1. Class names are capitalised; (dumpEmails -> DumpEmails)
2. Add the `{` to a new line;

This

```
class dumpEmails extends Command {
```

should be

```
class DumpEmails extends Command
{
```

I also recommend checking out about [PSR-x standards](https://blog.sideci.com/5-php-coding-standards-you-will-love-and-how-to-use-them-adf6a4855696). I left one of the blogs I think might help you kick start with them, but go further! :)

Last, but not least, do not forget `Command` Parent already lets you use its command line potential. So if you wish to output and debug, you can do so by using:

```
$this->info('Your message to inform');
$this->error('Your error message');
```

Comment: I have done above given changes, still same issue, my lumen version is 5.2.*

Comment: Hmmm, may I ask that you update with the changes please? So I have a map on how things are setting up there? :) 
As far as I am currently aware I would have believe that removing the `__construct` and setting the class properly at `Kernel` class would suffice **thinking**

Comment: I also made a small change that might be worth to try. 
If you could, remove the default path form your kernel class, pointing to your command class. If you notice, I just removed `\App\Console\Commands\dumpEmails` and left as `Commands\dumpEmails`.
That because `Kernel` might be already mapping it to the default folder

Comment: You should edit your question, not add an answer :P to keep track of what we are doing.
Give me a few minutes while I check this further

Comment: @hetalgohen I have it setup and running on my local. Will adapt my answer to what worked out.
basically, all you need to worry at this point is declaring it at your `Kernel` class. Make sure it is listed as `DumpEmails:::class` under your `$commands` parameter.
Also, make sure your file is `DumpEmails` and not `dumpEmails` and that the class declared within the file is also following the same rule. After check if your `php artisan list` is listing all existing commands and let me know if `1. it runs properly` and `2. If yours is now listed`

Comment: for me it is working now if I declare command in kernel file as : '\App\Console\Commands\DumpEmails',